# How does computer privacy law apply in Canada when program reports who's using it?

Tags: software, canada, privacy

If someone is hired to make a program for someone else, of course they don't need a EULA (end user license agreement) when they give the program to them as they are the owner. Is it possible for the person receiving the program to claim that the program violates their privacy if the program transmits information back to the developer (even in the event the program is not paid for i.e. a call home feature)? In other words, if someone doesn't pay the developer for software, can they claim that the software violates it's [authorized use of the computer](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-342.1.html) due to a [call home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoning_home) feature (which reports username, IP and network name)?

My last question got closed because it was too specific, but I thought some background information would be useful: someone hired me to build a program, which he never paid me for, but I know he is still using it due to a "call home" feature. He found this feature and claims it's in breach of http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-342.1.html

Comment: The cited law addresses "Unauthorized use of computer". I fail to see where you are using his computer. He is using his computer, and of his own choice is running a program which as a side effect is reporting its usage.

Answer (score 1):

If the person commissioning the program asked for the function or were made aware of it (through, say, an EULA) then this would be fine. If not, you are probably in breach of this law.